# python selenium chrome sign in script button not clickable

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, google-signin

Im making a chrome sign in script and the last part where the program should press the next button is not working.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=EN&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")
email = browser.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
email.send_keys("email")
browser.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
browser.implicitly_wait(4)
password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys("password")
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content/span').click()
```

I have tried using the name, ID and the xpath and none have worked

The error message says it is not clickable.  Any help would be greatly appreciated I'm very new to programming.

Comment: why not just find the element by id and click, its working fine for me using Jquery: browser.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click() : Jquery working fine for me is : $('#passwordNext').click(), so find_element_by_id should work, let us know if it works

Comment: thank you for the help when I try this though it gives me an unknown error, not sure why all the others worked and not this one

Comment: Interesting, another solution is you can execute the jQuery : $('#passwordNext').click() inside selenium's execute_script method

Comment: Thank you for the help I changed arround the code a little and added an implicit wait function which solved the problem the new code is     browser.implicitly_wait(4)
passwordID = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
passwordID.send_keys(password)